# how to flush a redirected stdout in C++

Tags: c++, redirect, stdout, flush

I have following code, compiled by Visual Studio 2008:

```
int main() {
    freopen ("C:\\temp\\stdout.txt","w",stdout);
    cout << "aaa" << endl;
    while (true) {
        string in = "";
        getline(cin, in);
        cout << "bbb" << endl;
        if (in.find("exit") != string::npos) {
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose (stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Open "C:\temp\stdout.txt" in Notepad++ to monitor the file change (by manually clicking on the file tab to refresh).

When running it:

it prints "aaa" immediately, which is correct;

then I input "asdf", however, "bbb" is not printed or flushed.

then I input "asdf", however, "bbb" is not printed or flushed.

then I input "asdf", however, "bbb" is not printed or flushed.

then I input "exit", the out put is like:

```
aaa
bbb
bbb
bbb
bbb
```

I've tried following ways to flush, but non of them can flush the string immediately.

```
cout << "bbb" << endl << flush;


cout << "bbb" << endl;
cout.flush();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're mixing the C approach to stream redirection and the C++.
Particularly in your code, it is safe to use:

```
ofstream fout("stdout.txt");
cout.rdbuf(fout.rdbuf());
```

to redirect the console output to a file.
No need to flush the stream manually because the std::endl manipulator does it for you.

The following code works fine:

```
// *****
#include <iostream>      // for I/O
#include <fstream>       // for file I/O
using namespace std;
// *****

int main() {
    // *****
    // freopen("stdout.txt", "w", stdout);
    ofstream fout("stdout.txt");
    cout.rdbuf(fout.rdbuf());
    // *****
    cout << "aaa" << endl;
    while (true) {
        string in = "";
        getline(cin, in);
        cout << "bbb" << endl;
        if (in.find("exit") != string::npos) {
            break;
        }
    }
    // *****
    // fclose (stdout);
    // *****
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. My test shows that the stdout.txt only get updated after program returned.

Comment: It seems that using ofstream and rdbuf can redirect the output; even I call an application by MyApp.exe > stdout.txt will do the same thing; However, how to get the file updated immediately after a cout << "asdf" << endl; is still the issue. Or it is not possible at all?

Comment: milesma, take a look at this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/basic_ostream/flush/). As I mentioned it should work that way. However, if your STL implementation or operating system conspires against, you can achieve that behavior by opening the file in append mode before calling cout and closing it after the call.
`fout.open("stdout.txt", std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::app);
cout.rdbuf(fout.rdbuf());
cout << "bbb" << endl;
fout.close();`

Comment: ...and if you really, really, really need to force the ofstream flush on Windows, take a look at [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/148505).

Comment: Your "append" suggestion works! I'm interested your comment on "if your STL implementation or operating system conspires against", could you explain more? Even without "append", the close+open will indicate that the "bbb" is flushed in time. So is the NotePad++ cheated me? But why use the "append" way caused the NotePad++ being notified the change of the file?

Comment: to be acurate, NotePad++ is not to be blamed. Because the timestamp for this file is not updated so NotePad++ just tells the truth. (when not using the append way)

Comment: It's good knowledge to know the Microsoft way of flush. However, I can not compile "_commit(CXXFileBuf.rdbuf()->fd());" fd is not found, _commit is not found. Any clues?

Comment: C and C++ file operations perform their own data caching but there's also a disk caching done by the operating system. So using C or C++ "flushing" not necessarily guaranties that the OS really updates the data on disk. Closing the file (in this case the ofstream) is an effective way of telling the operating system it has to immediately release resources assigned to the stream and consequently write all cached data to the file. On the other hand, opening the file in append mode just guaranties that _"all output operations happen at the end of the file, appending to its existing contents."_.

Comment: _ _commit will only function on 16-bit operating systesm. On 32-bit operating systems, you will need to link to Commode.obj. _

Comment: Verified. Project Properties | Linker | Input | Additional Dependencies | add commmode.obj

Comment: Last question (forgive me if too annoying): you mentioned "opening the file in append mode just guaranties that "all output operations happen at the end of the file, appending to its existing contents."" and "...you can achieve that behavior by opening the file in append mode before calling cout and closing it after the call. ". Are they conflict? (If I'm understanding correctly, you said the "append" did not guarantee flush, but why it magically works?! Further, why you know it?)

Comment: No, they are not conflict. What forces the flush is to close the stream. The whole process is: 1 - open (in append mode to start writing at the end of the file), 2 - write (output the string), and  3 - close (force the OS to flush). This is repeated on every iteration of the while loop.

Comment: OHHH, I see. "append" is not the magic, close "ofstream" is the key. Since every time we close "ofstream" and open in the next loop, in order to keep the original text, we have to use "append" mode. Silly me.